# How to suppress verbose error message in powershell?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Please, observe:

[image]

And here is the transcript:

```
PS C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB> $job = Start-Job { C:\Dayforce\854\db\tools\dbupgrade\DbUpgrade.exe -d C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB -db 854_dfadminportal }
PS C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB> C:\Dayforce\854\db\tools\dbupgrade\DbUpgrade.exe -d C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB -db 854_dfadminportal
Using timeout of 30 minutes per step.
Analyzing target DB state ...
Parsing upgrade steps ...
Found 1 new upgrade step(s). Upgrading the database ...
Dropping 2 runtime code items ...
Failed to apply DFVersion 20000
20000.sql: Divide by zero error encountered. (8134, 1)
       Total Step SQL duration = 00:00:00.000
Total Step Round Trip duration = 00:00:00.035, average = 00:00:00.035
                Total duration = 00:00:00.357
PS C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB> Receive-Job $job.Id
Using timeout of 30 minutes per step.
Analyzing target DB state ...
Parsing upgrade steps ...
Found 1 new upgrade step(s). Upgrading the database ...
Dropping 2 runtime code items ...
Failed to apply DFVersion 20000
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Failed to apply DFVersion 20000:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

20000.sql: Divide by zero error encountered. (8134, 1)
       Total Step SQL duration = 00:00:00.000
Total Step Round Trip duration = 00:00:00.031, average = 00:00:00.031
                Total duration = 00:00:00.339
PS C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB>
```

All I am doing is running the same executable. Once directly, once from within a background job. When receiving the output of the background job, extra error information is output. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: When you run the script manually, how do you run it? In a powershell Prompt? In the ISE? Some other way? What does the code look like?

Comment: @PetSerAl please, arrange your comment as an answer. It is hard to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I changed the question to show a direct example

Comment: ``$job = Start-Job { cmd /s /c `" '2>&1' C:\Dayforce\854\db\tools\dbupgrade\DbUpgrade.exe -d C:\Dayforce\854\db\SQL\ClientDB -db 854_dfadminportal `" }``